# Deploying Multiple Flask Apps On Server

Tags: apache, flask, localhost, virtualhost, wsgi

I am attempting to deploy a 2nd flask application to an apache webserver. I have added a 2nd listener to the httpd.conf file for 127.0.0.1:8868 because I am accessing the api through a gateway located on my machine. The first app I deployed was set up in a very similar fashion and works perfectly. The flask app works fine when launched from the .py file. I have attached excerpts from the httdpd.conf file, httpd-vhosts.conf file, and the web.wsgi file. It doesn't record any errors in the apache errors log and or the access logs. It will record it in the access and error logs if I have an error in the .wsgi file.  Having both listeners enabled also seems to interfere with the first application listening on port 5000.

httpd listeners:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:5000
Listen 127.0.0.1:8868
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>
        WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Users/me/web_apps/task_manager/app/index/web.wsgi
        <Directory C:/Users/me/web_apps/task_manager>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8868>
        WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Users/me/web_apps/template_autoupdate/app/index/web.wsgi
        <Directory C:/Users/me/web_apps/template_autoupdate>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

web.wsgi

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Users/me/web_apps/template_autoupdate/app")

from autoupdater import app as application
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [logging flask errors with mod\_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217490/logging-flask-errors-with-mod-wsgi)

Comment: Pandas was causing an issue. I followed solution on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782912/pandas-and-numpy-thread-safety and it worked.